# Finding Sound Recordists interested in collecting unique gunshots

Tags: field-recording, sound-libraries, gunshot

Are there sound archivists who would be interested in setting up field recordings of unique gunshots?  If so how might I go about finding them in my vicinity?

I don't have serious recording equipment, but I do have access to an outdoor shooting venue in Lancaster, PA, and a wide array of guns, loads, and suppressors.  So, for example, I could stage subsonic and supersonic shots, suppressed and unsuppressed, going out as far as 500 yards, in a range of calibers; as well as impacts into different media and even some reliable ricochets.

(This question inspired by an answer to [Origin of the traditional Hollywood silencer sound?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/29750/origin-of-the-traditional-hollywood-silencer-sound), where an amateur caught an interesting but low-fidelity sound.  There seems to be a lot of curiosity in doing a more controlled series with professional sound gear.)

Answer (score 1):

This may be of more interest to sound recordists/designers than archivists. One consideration is the location you have available - most serious gunshot libraries are recorded in quiet open locations, especially to get nice distant recordings that are very useful. If you've got the guns though I' sure someone here is interested, and you would be sure to get some good stuff. Where are you based?

Comment: Thanks.  Changed the question title to say "Recordists" instead of "Archivists," which I guess is what meant.  Also noted the location: Lancaster, PA.

Comment: Too far for me.. I imagine someone here might be interested though.

Comment: Are there other forums where recordists might gather where I could post the offer?

Comment: @feetwet There are recording forums, but not anything so specific. Your best bet might be finding a sound designer/recordist working locally who is interested. If there are any game development studios nearby the sound designers there may be a good bet.